# how to show =required information on a VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

For the required fields on my page, I'm getting the red bar next to the fields that indicate they are required but not the directions at the top of the page which says 'red bar' = required information.  I am including my mode = "edit" in my `<apex:pageblock>` ... ideas?

according to this site, that **should** do it...
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/How-to-display-quot-Required-information-quot-on-the-Page-Block/td-p/110572

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="EventExtension" tabStyle="Event" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Calendar" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Event.Subject),'New Event',Event.Subject)}" />
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Event Edit" mode="edit"  >

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >                  
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection ></apex:pageBlockSection>


    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Calendar Details" columns="2">         
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">               
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="System Information" columns="2">       
        </apex:pageBlockSection>


    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me. I think the solution is that you need to add a title to the first `pageBlockSection`. I can't explaint this issue, but if i put the first pageBlockSection without any title - the "= Required Information" label disappears:

```
<apex:page standardController="Event" extensions="EventExtension" tabStyle="Event" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Calendar" subtitle="Subtitle" />
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Event Edit" mode="edit"  >

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >                  
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Calendar Details">         
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thats so weird...

Comment: @mast0r For me, Required Information is appearing only for first pageblocksection.

Answer (score 0):

please add mode="edit"  to  and it should display = required information

```
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a weird issue that even after having **mode = "edit"** in **apex:pageBlock** the **| = required information** is only showing for first **apex:pageBlockSection**

so if you want to add **| = required information** only for the one **apex:pageBlockSection** then **mode = "edit"** will work, but if you want to go further into this, then just create a makeshift like

1. add a id to **apex:pageBlockSection**

   ```
    <apex:pageBlockSection  id="second_section" columns="2" title="This will WORK" collapsible="false" showHeader="true" >
   ```
2. now get the id using inspect element
   [image]
3. now just create the **| = required information** part using javascript in visualforce page

   ```
     window.onload = function() {
         var secondSection = document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id2:j_id30:second_section');
         var headerDiv = secondSection.children[0];
         headerDiv.innerHTML += '<span class="pbSubExtra"><span class="requiredLegend"><span class="requiredExampleOuter"><span class="requiredExample">&nbsp;</span></span><span class="requiredText"> = Required Information</span></span></span>';

     };
   ```

The output will be something like this
[image]